# Default path for RScript terminal command changes with sudo

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line, bash, sudo

I am trying to execute Rscripts from the terminal, but I can only get them to work by adding the `sudo`command. Running --verbose, I have been able to narrow down the problem to a difference in the default path used to execute the command:

```
username@user1: sudo Rscript --verbose -e 2+2
running
  '/usr/lib/R/bin/R --no-echo --no-restore -e 2+2'

[1] 4
```

That is the expected output.

Here, without sudo, the directory changes when calling Rscript:

```
username@user1:~$ Rscript --verbose -e 2+2
running
  '/opt/rstudio/latest/bin/R --no-echo --no-restore -e 2+2'

Rscript execution error: No such file or directory
```

When I first switched to Linux, I did install an instance of rstudio to that directory, so I believe the issue is that I've changed the default PATH somewhere. I just don't know where or how to find it. Classic learn-by-failing moment.

Attempted fixes: I've completely uninstalled R and RStudio, as well as the RStudio preference file (located `~/.local/share/rstudio`). Rebooted system. Reinstalled only R, problem persists.

Edit based on comments:

```
type Rscript
```

> Rscript is /usr/bin/Rscript

```
echo $PATH
```

> /opt/rstudio/latest/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin

```
ls -l /opt/rstudio/latest/bin/R
```

> ls: cannot access '/opt/rstudio/latest/bin/R': No such file or directory

Well, that was very helpful! So I just need to delete this extra nonsense I added to path.

Comment: (1) What is the output of `type Rscript`? (2) What is the output of `echo "$PATH"`? (3) What is the output of `ls -l /opt/rstudio/latest/bin/R`? // Please do not respond in comments; [edit] the question and add information there.

Comment: Based on your comment, I used `grep` to find the errant `export PATH`. Commenting it out solved the issue.